# Need some HTAccess Magic

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess, redirect

I am migrating to a new reseller hosting plan.  By default, they expect me to create a new cPanel account for every domain I add but this would be hugely inconvenient.

So I setup my addon domains in the following fashion:

```
/public_html/mydomain1.com/www/
/public_html/mydomain2.com/www/
```

The problem is, my Default domain in the account points to /public_html/ and cannot be changed by conventional methods.

I created a .htaccess file with the following data:

```
Rewrite Engine On
Rewrite Rule ^$ /mydefaultdomain.com/www/ [R=301,L]
```

The only problem is that it redirects to:

```
mydefaultdomain.com/mydefaultdomain.com/www/
```

How can I force it to use the subfolder but not show it in the finished URL?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I really got what you mean, but this sounds more like a job for VirtualHosts and DocumentRoot or maybe VirtualDocumentRoot which lets you do things like:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  UseCanonicalName off
  ServerName mydefaultdomain.com
  ServerAlias *.mydomain*.com
  VirtualDocumentRoot /public_html/%2/%1
</VirtualHost>
```